# Liferay module (OSGi bundle) stays in "Stopping"

Tags: liferay, osgi, liferay-7, jstack, gogo-shell

Sometimes when I stop my Liferay module (for instance when I put a new version of its JAR in `deploy/`) the module refuses to stop.

While the module should go to "Resolved" state, it stays in the "Stopping" state forever:

[image: OSGi lifecycle]

Usually it is due to a thread not terminated somewhere, or a network connection not properly closed, and it is often a pain to investigate.

**My question**: How to find out more efficiently what this Liferay module's problem is?

What I tried:

- In Gogo Shell `diag <module id>` does not seem to provide any valuable information about why the module refuses to leave the "Stopping" state.
- [jstack](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/jstack.html) outputs thousands of lines, the vast majority of which is outside of the Liferay module in question. If there was a way to show jstack information for only my module that would be wonderful.

Comment: Are you using an Activator inside your module? The state stopping means that Activator.stop() method was called but did not yet return. One of your threads should be in that method.

Comment: @ChristianSchneider: Added my ServiceActivator.

Comment: You are on the good track to solve the issue with jstack. It created a thread dump, but most of the threads have about 5-10 lines. Look for the thread that is much bigger, especially that has ServiceActivator.stop method call in it. Then you will see what is causing the deadlock or long sleeping.

Comment: @BalazsZsoldos: Looking for ServiceActivator.stop is a great tip! Do you want to write an answer about it? Or I can write it if you have no time.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul I think looking at the thread dump and trying to find the code snippet it is more an advice than a real answer. If you want to make a response about it with the cause of the block, feel free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, find the PID of your webapp server:

```
ps aux | grep tomcat
```

Adapt the command if you are running another server than tomcat, or if you have several instances running.

Then, dump all threads of that server to a file:

```
jstack 12345 > jstack.txt
```

Where 12345 is the PID you found in the first step.

Then, look at the source code of your bundle, and find the service activator. It typically looks like this:

```
package fr.free.nrw;

[import section]

public class ServiceActivator implements BundleActivator {

    private ServiceRegistration registration;

    @Override
    public void start(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
        registration = context.registerService(
            MyService.class.getName(), new MyServiceImpl(), null);
    }

    @Override
    public void stop(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
        registration.unregister();
    }
}
```

Take note of:

- the namespace,
- the class name,
- the stopping method name.

For instance in the example above they are `fr.free.nrw`, `ServiceActivator` and `stop`, and from these three get the full name `fr.free.nrw.ServiceActivator.stop`.

Now open `jstack.txt` and search for the full name. Even though the file is thousands of lines long, there will most probably only be one hit, and that is the problematic thread:

```
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.unregister(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:222)
at fr.free.nrw.ServiceActivator.stop(ServiceActivator.java:30)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$4.run(BundleContextImpl.java:830)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$4.run(BundleContextImpl.java:1)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.stop(BundleContextImpl.java:823)
```

In this file, go up to the beginning of the paragraph, which will be something like this:

```
"fileinstall-/home/nico/p/liferay/osgi/modules" #37 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f39480e3000 nid=0x384f waiting on condition [0x00007f395d169000]
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000000eb8defb8> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
```

With this information in hand, you will known what kind of threading problem is going on, and you will be able to solve it with usual Java thread debugging techniques ([1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/tooldescr016.html#BABEHDDH) [2](https://dzone.com/articles/how-analyze-java-thread-dumps)).

Answer (score 0):

The Activator you shared should never block on the stop method. So I doubt it can cause the behavior you described.

Comment: It can be. The stop method of the Activator is called synchronously. He unregisters a service and that causes the call of synchronous service listeners (and service trackers). On ServiceTracker might get deadlocked.

Comment: Ah .. interesting. So the reason could be some badly written service tracker or listener in some other bundle.

Comment: Could be. I was talking on the service tracker level, but one can easily make a mistake on higher levels, too. E.g.: One writes some business logic with sleeping or waiting in the setter of a service reference (or in the activate method) of a DS component. These code snippets are often called on the same thread as the service registration is done as they are based on synchronous service trackers.